# Compactness of $Tf=f(\sin(x))$ for $f\in C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, arzela-ascoli

Let $T$ be defined as $Tf(x)=f(\sin(x))$. I've attempted using Arzela Ascoli to check the compactness of this operator. Boundedness is no problem to show and I think I can prove equicontinuity as follows.

Consider $f_n\in B$ where $B$ is some bounded subset of $C([0,1])$

Let $|x-y|<\delta$

$$\implies |\sin(x)-\sin(y)|<\delta$$

By uniform continuity of the continuous functions $f_n$ on a compact set we have

$$|f_n(\sin(x))-f_n(\sin(y))|<\epsilon$$

This delta only depends on $\epsilon$ and our point thus proving the equicontinuity of $Tf_n$. By Arzela-Ascoli this operator appears to be compact, but I believe this is not the case. This appears similar to the identity operator on $C([0,1])$, only with a contraction in the argument of the function. The identity operator is not compact in infinite dimensional Banach spaces. Any thoughts or counter-examples?

Comment: Why would it be compact? Surely $T(B(0,1))$ contains much of the unit ball? It is not clear how Arzela Ascoli fits in here?

Comment: @copper.hat I agree that it should not be compact. I'm not sure why the Arzela-Ascoli argument fails and I'm looking for a counter-example to compactness such as a sequence of bounded functions such that $Tf_n$ does not have a convergent subsequence

Comment: You didn't show uniform continuity. You can't. You would have to show that there is a $\delta$ that works for all $f$, not one specific one. The $\sin$ thing is a red herring. Think of $T$ as an isomorphism to $C[0,\sin 1]$.

Comment: @copper.hat Because f is continuous on a compact interval it is uniformly continuous. Then $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|<|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(\sin(x))-f(\sin(y))|<\epsilon$. So assuming the uniform continuity of $f(x)$ we can prove the uniform continuity of $f(\sin(x))$ this is of course not the equicontinuity that we need to apply arzela-ascoli, but I'm not sure why there would be any issues.

Comment: Any single $f$ is uniformly continuous, but there is no $\delta$ that works for all. Take $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$. If they were equicontinuous then you could obtain some odd results.

Comment: @EvanGorman To say the same thing as copper.hat slightly differently, pay attention to the order of the quantifiers. You'll see that you need to pick $\delta$ independently of $n$.

Comment: Your operator is the composition of the projection $C[0,1] \to C[0,\sin(1)]$ with an isomorphism $C[0,\sin(1)] \to C[0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=(\frac {h(x)} c)^{n}$ where $c =\sin \, 1$ and $h$ is any continuous function with the following properties:

a) $o\leq h(t) \leq c$ for all $t$

b) There exists a unique point $s$ in $[0,1]$ such that $h(s)=c$ and this point belongs to $[0,c]$

It is easy to construct such a  function.

Then $(f_n)$ is norm bounded in $C[0,1]$. If $T$ is compact there exists $n_k$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $(\frac {h(\sin\, x)} c)^{n_k}$ converges uniformly. The limit of this sequence is $0$ when $\sin \, x \neq s$ and $1$ for $\sin \, x=s$. But uniform limit of continuous functions are continuous. [Note that there is a unique $x$ with $\sin \, x=s$.].  Conclusion: $T$ is not compact.

Comment: Explicit definition of $h$: $h(x)=x$ for $0 \leq x \leq c$ and $h(x)=\frac {c(1-x)} {1-c}$ for $c \leq x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

"The $\delta$ only depends on $\epsilon$" is not true - it depends on $\epsilon$ and $n$.